# replace a pattern by \x

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings in which accented characters are coded in hex like this :

extrémité > extr`\X2\00`**E9**`\X0\`mit`\X2\00`**E9**`\X0\`

So I plan to replace `\X2\00`**(charcode)**`\X0\` by `\X`**(charcode)**
but I can't write `'\x'` in :

`out.replace(/\X2\00/g,'\x');`

How can I do that ?

---

This doesn't work neither :

```
out.replace(/2\00/g,'');
```

---

This is for a parser, here is a file line :

```
#242= IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE('Num\X2\00E9\X0\ro',$,IFCLABEL('5'),$);
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your problem is that you can't write `\x`, because it's getting escaped? Have you tried escaping the escape sequence? Example: `\\x`

Comment: Have you tride `out.replace(/2\\00/g, '');`?

Comment: @Brynden : no : `out.replace(/\X2\00/g,'\\x');` > \xE9X0 and `out.replace(/\\X2\\00/g,'\\x');` > X2�E9X0

Comment: @Rick : no : `out.replace(/2\\00/g, '');` > X2�E9X0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape backslashes in JavaScript regular expressions and strings.

From your comments I understand that your source data (in a file) looks like this:

```
\X2\00E9\X0\
```

Note that if you want to reproduce this data (for testing), in the console, you need to escape those backslashes. In JavaScript notation the above data is represented as `'\\X2\\00E9\\X0\\'`.

Also, to generate the accented letters you could use [`charFromCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode), and use `replace()` with a callback function:

```js
// note that in JS strings, backslashes need to be escaped to get 
// the text as it appears in your file. This is just to mimic the file input
var str = 'extr\\X2\\00E9\\X0\\mit\\X2\\00E9\\X0\\';

// .. and also in JS regexes, the backslashes need to be escaped.
str = str.replace(/\\X2\\00(..)\\X0\\/g, function(_, match) {
    // match is now the two letter hex code, convert to number and then
    // to character, and return it as replacement 
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match,16));
});

document.write(str);
```

Comment: It doesn't work :( But the backslashes are not escaped in my strings, I get an index with `str.indexOf('\X2\00')`

Comment: If the backslashes are not escaped, then the first one is meaningless: `\X`== `X` and `\00` is the `NUL` character. So what happens if you `console.log` the values. Do you see the backslashes or not?

Comment: No if I console.log the initial value I get `X2�E9X0` (but indexOf finds `\X2\00`)

Comment: Then why do you say there is a backslash before the `X`? It really serves no purpose at all. I have adapted my answer and code to this information.

Comment: Could you give some feedback? Does it work with the adapted code? Do you understand why the backslash before the `X` serves no purpose?

Comment: Yes, but I write a parser and this is the way accented characters are coded into the file. I confirm that there is 1 backslash before the 'X' and the string for `extrémité` is `extr\X2\00E9\X0\mit\X2\00E9\X0\` also into the file (wich is ANSI). So I'm afraid your code doesn't work whith my str.

Comment: Wait, you see the backslash in the file, so I am not asking in JavaScript, but in the file, in an editor? Can you please first make sure you understand escaping in JavaScript, and that if you write it as a JavaScript string, you need to double the backslashes? Please confirm you understand this. Can you put a file example in your question (don't say it is a string, because that is misleading), and say it is the file contents? That will help to solve the ambiguity about backslashes.

Comment: Yes I know that a backslash needs to be escaped by another backslash .. I didn't say that it was a .js file (it's .ifc). I've added a line sample above and that's what I see in an editor. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I reverted my answer to use escaped backslashes, because that is what will match the file. Now an important aspect: how do you read the file? Can you share the code? It is important to know how this is done.

Comment: Well it doesn't work :( I would say that the code should simply work in the console with `str = 'D\X2\00E9\X0\calage'` since this string is exactly the same into the file ... The whole code is a mess (and it's not online) but I read the file with a simple FileReader (+readAsText).

Comment: The fact that you think that typing that in the console should work, just illustrates you do not understand backslash escaping. You need to ***double*** the backslashes to mimic the file contents exactly. Single backslashes would escape the next character, which is not what the file contents have. Please read about using backslashes in JavaScript strings.

Comment: Ok, In fact I had misunderstood the fact that `str.indexOf('\X2\00')` works in the console whith my str ... Your solution works fine in context (with the read text). Many thanks !